# Retrieve polygon smallest MBR

Tags: postgis, geometry, algorithm, coordinate-system, generalization

I have a postgis table containing polygons. I want to transform my polygons  to 4 points polygons : retrieve the smallest MBR.

Here comes an illustration of what I want :

[image]

My original polygon is in pink color. 
I guess, it will be quite easy to get the MBR (with ST_Envelope and BBox function)
But is there an easy way to get what I want?

Any ideas? Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some 11 years late to the party, but I think this does what you want (well, from v2.5.0 which was probably after you asked!)

https://postgis.net/docs/ST_OrientedEnvelope.html

Comment: It seems to be that, indeed ! The algorithm is now also available in Processing in QGIS. Eleven years have passed ... ;-))

Answer (score 3):

For that simple example you have there, the ST_ConvexHull would give you that answer.  For the more complex case, haven't thought much about it, but my guess is that you can

1) Take the ST_ConvexHull - 
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_ConvexHull.html

If you are using PostGIS 1.5+
2) Then get the ST_LongestLine of the convexhull ST_LongestLine(ST_ConvexHull(geom), ST_ConvexHull(geom))  That will give you two corners of the rectangle (though there is another part -- I'm missing) since those two corners may not be the diagonal)
http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_LongestLine.html

You may also want to take a look at the code for ST_MinimumBoundingCircle -- its currently just implemented as a plpgsql function -- but what you are doing I think is a simplification of that.

http://www.postgis.org/documentation/manual-1.5SVN/ST_MinimumBoundingCircle.html

Answer (score 3):

You can find it described here:
http://www.cgafaq.info/wiki/Minimum_Rectangle_Enclosing_Points

Which leads to:
http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~orm/maer.html

Answer (score 3):

A complete answer can be found [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points) however in summary:

- [S] rotate the polygon to match one of its edges with **X** axis
- compute `minmax` of **X** and **Y** for vertices
- this gives you a candidate for minimum area rectangle (MAR) or MBR
- store the area of (x2-x1)*(y2-y1)
- repeat from [S] for all edges
- find the minimum area which corresponds to MBR
- rotate found [[x1,y1],[x2,y2]] by -angle applied in [S]

Done.