# How to find the maximum-area-rectangle inside a convex polygon?

Tags: polygon, geometry, algorithm

In this post we are looking for **algorithms** / **ideas** on how to find the ***maximum-area-rectangle*** *inside a **convex polygon***.

In the following figure, numbers are the areas of the fitted rectangles. As shown a desired rectangle can vary in each dimension and can be in any angle.

**Edit:**

> We don't have any clear idea how to deal with the problem mentioned as
>   so we asked here. Nevertheless, we **guess** the maximum-area-rectangle
>   may be one of those that has one edge ***aligned*** on (not necessarily the
>   same length edge, of course) an edge of the polygon.

[image]

Comment: Could you specify what software you are using? Also, post your work this far, or the general approach you have worked out to solve this. Maybe someone can improve what you have done already. In my experience that'll result in far more useful answers than just posting a question "out of the blue".

Comment: Closely related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points.

Comment: @Martin Software: Programming in `Python` then will be in `Fortran` if required. We have a guess that based on our previous post [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points) also mentioned above by `whuber` that may be a rectangle with an edge in common with polygon would be an answer.

Comment: @Developer The maximum area rectangle doesn't have to have a common edge with the polygon. If you take the polygon you have now and change the left edge into two edges (as if building a triangle on that side) the answer won't change although you no longer have a common edge.

Comment: @JakubKania We updated the post. We meant to be aligned on an edge not necessarily to be the same length of edge, so. Anyway, this is a guess, no prove or experiments yet.

Comment: @Developer Well, all I meant was it doesn't have to touch the edge. My guess is that the only sure thing is it will touch the polygon with at least two of it's corners.

Comment: Your problem is a really interesting one, and I think I managed to find a solving algorithm [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/) and [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.47.5945).

Comment: @nickves Thanks for the links. Would you please put these info as answer with a little explanation of the algorithms? It will be potentially a good answer to be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

Some notes too big to put into a comment (though this doesn't suggest an obvious algorithm):

The punch line **(EDITED)**: At least two vertices of the maximum area rectangle must lie on the boundary of the polygon (i.e. along an edge, or at a vertex).  And if the maximum area rectangle is not a square, then at least three vertices must lie on the boundary of the polygon.

I proved it to myself in four steps:

*Note #1*: At least one vertex of the maximum area rectangle will always lie on the boundary of the polygon.  This is pretty obvious, but a proof could go like this (by contradiction): Suppose you had a "maximal" rectangle with no vertex on the boundary of the polygon.  That means there would be at least a little room around each of its vertices.  So you could expand your rectangle a bit, contradicting its maximality.

*Note #2*: At least *two* vertices of the maximum area rectangle will always lie on the boundary of the polygon.  A proof could go like this (again by contradiction): Suppose you had a "maximal" rectangle with only one vertex on the boundary (guaranteed by Note #1).  Consider the two edges not adjacent to that vertex.  Since their endpoints are NOT on the boundary, there's a little room around each.  So either of those edges could be "extruded" a bit, expanding the polygon's area and contradicting its maximality.

*Note #3*: There are two *diagonally opposite* vertices of the maximum area rectangle that lie on the boundary of the polygon.  (We know from Note #2 that there are at least two, but not necessarily that they're across from each other.)  But again by contradiction, if the only two boundary vertices were adjacent, then the opposite edge (neither of whose vertices are on the boundary) could be extruded a little bit, increasing the area of the rectangle and contradicting its maximality.

*Note #4*: **(EDITED)** If the maximum area rectangle is not a square, then three of its vertices will lie on the boundary of the polygon.

To prove, suppose that's not the case, i.e. that the maximum area rectangle is not a square, but only two of its vertices are on the boundary of the polygon.  I'll show how to construct a bigger rectangle, contradicting the maximality.

Call the vertices of the rectangle `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.  Without loss of generality, assume that `B` and `D` are the two that are on the polygon boundary.  Since `A` and `C` are on the interior of the polygon, there's some wiggle room around them (represented with circles around `A` and `C` in the picture below).  Now draw a circle around the rectangle, and slide points `A` and `C` a little bit around the circle by the same amount (to make `A'` and `C'`, pictured below) so that the new rectangle `A'BC'D` is more square than the original rectangle.  This process creates a new rectangle that is also within the original polygon and has a larger area.  This is a contradiction, so the proof is done.

[image: Constructing a new rectangle]

To believe that proof, you have to convince yourself that the area of a rectangle inscribed in a circle increases as it becomes "more square" (i.e. the difference between the edge lengths gets smaller).  You also need the polygon to be convex so that the new lines are all within it.  And there are probably other little details getting swept under the rug, but I'm fairly sure they all work out.

Comment: Note #4 is fishy, because "wiggling" the two other vertices will create non-rectangles.

Comment: True. However your visualization of the 4th example is not quite right (if 2 vertices are on the polygon boundary, you can't stretch it further). I can't find exactly how to explain it though (tried writing a comment but got too messy), but I trust you are right.

Comment: I believe there are counterexamples to note #4.  The ones I have found take some involved calculation to show, though; the simplest is a perturbation of an irregular hexagon (a square with two opposite corners slightly cut off).

Comment: Agreed that Note #4 is fishy.  I'll take a closer look this evening and either fix it or remove it.

Comment: +1 That is a nice resolution of the difficulty.  Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 3):

I have done a very quick and hideous sketch about your green note in the question. I couldn't post it as comment so I had to write an answer, even if it isn't one.
I believe that in the image below we have a maximum area rectangle (not perfect, it's just a sketch made on Paint to give an idea), and I don't think you can find a bigger one which would have a common side with the borders of the black plygon...
However I can be wrong, in that case you have all my apologies.
[image: Quick Sketch I made on Paint]

Comment: Good point (+1).  There's a much simpler counterexample, though: consider the problem of inscribing a maximal-area rectangle within a regular octagon.  It's easy to see (and easy to prove by first finding a maximal square within the octagon's circumcircle) that the corners of the solution coincide with alternating vertices of the octagon and that this solution is substantially larger than any edge-aligned inscribed rectangle.

Comment: Actually (I just have a big doubt right now), the external smallest rectangle (the ones from [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22895/how-to-find-the-minimum-area-rectangle-for-given-points)) of this polygon hasn't got the same orientation as one of the sides, has it ? (I would see it the same orientation as my red rectangle)

Comment: That polygon isn't convex, by the way.  The original question does restrict to convex polygons.

Comment: @csd That's a great point, but Saryk is still correct, as my counterexample shows. Saryk, there is no problem with the minimum area bounding rectangle: it's easy to prove (rigorously) that it must include a side of the convex hull. I believe the maximum area inscribed rectangle (of a convex polygon) need only have two vertices touching the boundary, no more.

Answer (score 2):

Most other algorithms find the maximum area rectilinear rectangle inscribed in a convex polygon, and have a complexity of `O(log n)`.   I don't think your guess that the max area polygon is aligned with one of the sides is correct, because all you would need to do is rotate the polygon `n` times, resulting in a complexity of `O(n log n)`, and in my brief research I couldn't find anything saying it was that easy.

However, the paper [Largest Inscribed Rectangles in Convex Polygons](http://page.mi.fu-berlin.de/jeschmid/Knauer2010.pdf) by  Knauer, et. al.,  describes an approximation algorithm that will get you close to the right answer.

As best as I understand the algorithm, it builds on top of one of the known axis-aligned max area polygons, and then randomly samples points inside the polyon space, generates multiple axis from those random samples, iterates over those axis and applies the axis-aligned algorithm to each one, and then returns the biggest rectangle in that set.

Comment: Is there perhaps a typo in the first sentence? There cannot possibly be a O(log(n)) algorithm because merely reading in the coordinates is a O(n) operation!

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: @dangerousdave - Found an alternate link for however long it lasts....

Answer (score 1):

Maybe have a look at this [largest interior rectancle implementation](https://github.com/lukasalexanderweber/lir). It uses the algorithm described in [this paper](https://journals.ut.ac.ir/article_71280_2a21de484e568a9e396458a5930ca06a.pdf). An example Image is

[image]