# How to create bounding boxes that are not orientated to the north?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I want to create bounding boxes around polygons, the bounding boxes will then be used in a ST_Hausdorffdistance to determain the squarness of every polygon. My first choice is using the ST_Envelope function but the problem with this is that all the envelopes are orientated to the north.

The result is the following image.

[image: bouding box created with ST_Envelope]

The following image is how I would like it to look.

[image: bouding box created with minimum bounding geometry tool in ArcGIS]

This is created with the Minimum bounding geometry tool in ArcGIS. Is there any possibilty to do this in PostGIS?

I tried doing it with the Box2D function in PostGIS, but I can't seem to find the way to save the geometry to the geom column?

Comment: Maybe try this?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/133662/18189

Comment: Or also: https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3176

Comment: This question does specifically ask for a PostGIS solution.  But the question listed as a duplicate does not provide such a solution.  (@dbaston's second comment, linking to the PostGIS trac, does though.)